# sending email from aws ec2 (service limit request refused)

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, amazon-ec2, mybb

I run a simple mybb forum on AWS EC2 and I wish to send notifications to my users.

I have tried to request aws regarding upgrade of my email sending quota but they have refused.
Also tried SES but request is refused again.

Is there any way out I can reach my audience?
Wondering if I can do a http GET request to a SMTP server to send emails?

Answer (score 1):

You definitely don't want to send emails directly from your ec2 server, and I would generally recommend SES instead - but if for whatever reason that doesn't suit your needs, any SMTP server should work fine - doesn't need to be an GET request, just plug in your SMTP credentials to whatever service you are using - gmail, ses, mailchimp, sendgrid, mailgun - pretty much any service is available to you and should work fine.

Comment: I think port 25, 465, 587 all are blocked by aws. So, connection to SMTP would also be throttled?

Comment: they are not blocked 'by aws', at least not in any way that you can't unblock. you have control over which ports are open to the outside world thru your security policies, that you control.